# Z3 Installation with Cryptol by Galois

Tags: installation, cryptography, z3, cryptol

I am currently starting some work on Cryptol but for Cryptol I need z3. Z3 is required to even run it.
I have downloaded the latest Z3 version from gitHub but I am not sure how to install it/set it up for use by cryptol.
I am on a windows 10 PC. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to build on your own, here're the instructions: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3#building-z3-on-windows-using-visual-studio-command-prompt

But you're better off just getting the nuget package and installing it directly, here's the latest: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases/download/z3-4.8.10/Microsoft.Z3.x64.4.8.10.nupkg (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-install-package for how to install this manually.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely try this. What I found out is that I need to specify the already downloaded files in the system path, but I don't know how to specify them so Cryptol can find them. If you know the commands in the system path it would be of great use to me as well, in case I fail to do the other one.
Or rather I should reiterate - how should I name Z3 in the system path so it can be globally usable by Cryptol

Comment: Probably simply add it to your windows path.